# avg_page_space_used_in_percent and fill factor

Tags: sql-server, index, fragmentation

`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` contains `column avg_page_space_used_in_percent`.

How does this fit in with the fill factor of an index?

**For example:**

I have index `idx_HeaderInfo`

I create the index with a fill factor of `80%`.

If I then immediately look at avg_page_space_used_in_percent do I see:

- 100
- 80

I ask because I need a way of rebuilding or reorganising based on internal fragmentation rather than external and I don't want to create logic to rebuild/reorg if a avg_page_space_used_in_percent < 75 if the fill factor in the first place is 70 for instance.

Comment: You should rebuild or reorganize based on `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` why are you using other column details

Comment: avg_fragmentation_in_percent only identifies external fragmentation. I'm after internal fragmentation only. The environment I work in is on a SAN where data is stored across many disks, therefore is always random.

Comment: It should always be `% of page (8K)`, not `% of (8K * fill factor / 100)`. Did you try it? Seems like a simple test.

Comment: Yeah I realized I could try it out after posted. Will answer my question :)

Answer (score 1):

`avg_page_space_used_in_percent` does not care about fill factor.

Therefore if you set an index to have fill factor of 40, your `avg_page_space_used_in_percent` will straight away be 40.

Answer (score 0):

@Hpk, since you have already answered your own question, my answer will provide you some food for thoughts :

> I ask because I need a way of rebuilding or reorganizing based on internal fragmentation rather than external and I don't want to create logic to rebuild/reorg if a avg_page_space_used_in_percent < 75 if the fill factor in the first place is 70 for instance.

I believe you are writing your own scripts to detect fragmentation and address it based on some criteria. Remember - [there is a cost to reinvent the wheel](http://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/) *(courtesy of Aaron Bertrand)*

I would suggest you to look into - a [more intelligent way of addressing your index fragmentation issues](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html). *(hint: SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance by Ola hallengren)*

The benefit of using Ola's script is that it has logging functionality *[logs to `dbo.CommandLog` table]*  which over time will become a gold mine and you can get real value out of it.

**e.g.**

- If you are deploying index maintenance, then you can use `dbo.CommandLog` to find out what indexes are frequently getting fragmented often, the time taken to defragment them and if you join to `sys.indexes` then you can tie up `FILL FACTOR` and adjust it.  Check - [monitoring-for-endless-index-defragmenting](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2013/11/monitoring-for-endless-index-defragmenting/).
- Also, if you have DatabaseIntegrityCheck - CHECKDB solution, then you can find out [how long it takes to perform CHECKDB](https://sqlnotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/knowing-your-checkdb-duration-times-using-ola-hallengren-maintenance-scripts/).

Also, Brent has an excellent post on - [Stop Worrying About SQL Server Fragmentation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/)